# Find all clients in network

Tags: c++, c, windows, tcp

I'm writing client-server application and I need my server to find all clients in some network. I've already found some info here: [Discovering clients on a wifi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158721/discovering-clients-on-a-wifi-network), but I still don't understand how to implement this. Maybe somebody can say where I can find some code examples.

Thanks in advance.

PS. Working on c++, windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally TCP/IP is used as a communication protocol between client and server. For Windows platform Winsock library is used to implement TCP/IP. The server binds and listens on a port for incoming connections. Just like a webserver like stackoverflow listens by default on port 80 and then client (browsers) connects to it.

Here is a [link to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [Here is sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Normally all the client connects to server which listens on a well defined port. The server is only one hence the IP address and port is well know to all the client and hence they can connect to it.

In you case you want your server to have ablity to discover all the clients in the network. To achieve this the server needs to broadcast to network some message. The client will receive this message and will respond to the server that they are available on such IP and they can connect to server or provide additional information to server. Normally instead of broadcast, multicast is used which is limited broadcast. All the clients and server will subscribe to the multicast group which is a special kind of IP address. When server send a message to this multicast address all the client, which are subscribers of this address will receive this message and can respond back. Here is a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Edit:** you can also use boost lib to implement multicast: [sender eg.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/sender.cpp), [receiver eg.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/receiver.cpp)